# How can I make CKEditor update my backing data object when I am looking at Source?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

When my users make changes to the edit window it seems like the backing data object is update constantly. However when the user clicks on [SOURCE] and makes changes then it seems there is no update.

I added the following to my code:

```
        ck.on('mode', function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
            });
        });
```

This senses when the user returns from [SOURCE] to normal view and when that happens it updates my data.

However when the user stays in [SOURCE] view and clicks save on my screen it does not pick up the latest changes. Is there a way I can listen to changes in the [SOURCE] view and then update my backing datastore as these changes are made?

Comment: Hi Marilou,
I facing same problem when I paste code in source area and submitting form then content not save. Can you paste your complete code of ckeditor directives
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Can you look @ https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor

Ready to use Ckeditor Directive

Answer (score 1):

You could always add a "blur" directive and retrieve the data from [SOURCE] on blur...

```
app.directive('blur', function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(attrs.blur);
        });
    };
});

$scope.getCkData = function () {$scope.ckData = ck.getData();};


<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" blur="getCkData()">Default</textarea>
```

Now, from looking at CK Editor, when you click the "source" button, a new textarea is overlaid on the editor window. So, you may need to add the blur using a jquery selector.

```
$('#editor1 > textarea').attr('blur', 'getCkData()');
```

So, this way whenever someone leaves the source or wysiwyg view, the model gets updated.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into this and see how it works. If okay I will accept.